# Selenium - How to adjust the mouse speed when moving a slider?

Tags: python, selenium

I've got this code to bypass captcha basically:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import sys

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(sys.argv[1])
    time.sleep(2)
    slider = driver.find_element_by_id('nc_2_n1z')
    move = ActionChains(driver)
    move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(400, 0).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
except:
    pass
```

Everything works but when I execute this code, it moves the slider very fast (probably less than 1 second) so I can't bypass the `Slide to verify` captcha. From start to finish moving the slider, I want it to take 3-5 seconds so it'll act more like a human when moving the slider. Is it possible to adjust the speed when moving the slider ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by splitting the below line 
                                 move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(400, 0).release().perform()

You have to click and hold for the desired seconds then release

```
move.click_and_hold(slider).perform()
sleep(2)
move.move_by_offset(400, 0).release().perform()
```

However i am not sure the ask can handle captcha as most of the modern captcha can figure out if you are running script